# AJAX issue : button doesn't responsed anymore

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Last night I had issue with registration where php was saving null data to my database when ajax was used but with a help of stack overflow the issue was resolved. I was sending data in url and rather than using $_GET i used $_POST, problem solved so this morning I thought lets do the same with login page but this time when I add ajax to it the login button it does nothing, it just clicks and does nothing

what I was trying to do was when user login with correct info it goes to home page index.php but when the user try to log in with wrong info then it echo invalid. so I was trying to echo it in index.php rather than taking user to new page.

the following is the code i was working on.this one is saved as index.php where user puts there details.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    echo "<form action='login_parse.php' method='post' style='display: inline-block'>
    Username: <input type='text' name='username' id='username' />
    Password: <input type='password' name='password' id='password' />
    <input type = 'button' value='login' id='submit' onclick='hello2()'/>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "<form action='signup.php' method='post' style='display: inline-block'>";
    echo "&nbsp";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Signup'>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "<div id='ack1'></div>";

} else {
    echo "<form style='display: inline-block'>";
    echo "<p>You are logged in as ".$_SESSION['username']."";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "<form action='logout_parse.php' method='post' style='display: inline-block'>";
    echo "&nbsp";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='logout'>";
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

this one is saved as ajax.js

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}

  var HTTP = loadXMLDoc();

function hello2(){

  var username = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('username').value);
  var password = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('password').value);
  var url = "login_parse.php?username="+username+"&password="+password;
HTTP.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (HTTP.readyState==4 && HTTP.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("ack1").innerHTML=HTTP.responseText;
    }
  }
HTTP.open("POST", url ,true);
HTTP.send();
}
```

and at last this one is saved as login_parse.php

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once("connect.php");

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET["username"]);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string( md5 ($_GET["password"]));
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    } else{
        echo "INVALID login information.";
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

am I doing something wrong, do I have to use ajax just to echo invalid in index.php

Comment: u are not able to call hello2 function

Comment: i did link my ajax.js in my header "<script src = "ajax.js"></script>" so is that calling hello2 function

Comment: if you have linked it it will call hello2() and will send data also.

Comment: i have done it <input type = 'button' value='login' id='submit' onclick='hello2()'/>"; but nothing is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the fixes for the ajax code not displaying the invalid login message.

First i removed the function call for the hello2 function and placed in a javascript event at within a script tag at the bottom of the page.  This made it easier for me to conduct tests. You will have to add the id submit-button to your button html.

The previous echo in your index php file will look like this now.

```
    echo "<form action='login_parse.php' method='post' style='display: inline-block'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username' id='username' />
Password: <input type='password' name='password' id='password' />
<input id='submit-button' type = 'button' value='login' id='submit' />";
```

Here is the javascript that will before the closing body tag of your index.php file:

```
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
<script>


//return XMLHTTP request and store it
var HTTP = loadXMLDoc();

//on click event for #submit-button
var submitEvent = document.getElementById("submit-button").onclick = function(){

    hello2(HTTP);



};

</script>
```

This is were I found the main problem. I made the variable xmlhttp have global scope by placing it at the top your ajax.js code.

I found this problem initially by changed the following line of code:

```
 document.getElementById("ack1").innerHTML= HTTP.responseText;
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("ack1").innerHTML= "it worked";
```

By doing this I discovered that your function call at this point was working but your HTTP.onreadystatechange=function(){} was unable to access the responseText.

Here is the new ajax.js file code below:

```
 //moved variable outside of functions to give it the global scope
var xmlhttp;

function loadXMLDoc()
{



if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}



function hello2(HTTP){

  var username = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('username').value);
  var password = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('password').value);

  var url = "login_parse.php?username="+username+"&password="+password;


HTTP.onreadystatechange=function()
  {

  if (HTTP.readyState===4 && HTTP.status === 200){

    document.getElementById("ack1").innerHTML= HTTP.responseText;



    }
  };//<--was missing a semicolon ;

  HTTP.open("POST", url ,true);


HTTP.send();


}
```

Fix for PHP code so that you don't have to refresh index.php to show the You are "logged in as ..." message.

Place this php code before any other php code in you index.php file so that you can access your session variables.

```
             //start the session so that you can echo session variables on this page
             session_start();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have already done that, the question im asking is the button isnt working it meant to load index.php when user have right info and echo invalid but when i remove ajax from it, it works but echo invalid displays on new page.

Comment: i see I will look further into the problem

Comment: thanks im too working for a solution i will post on it if i find any

Comment: you are using get parameters with form using post method. That is part of the problem change your php code to use $_GET['username'] or $_REQUEST['username'] and you will see what I mean. I will try and help more later.

Comment: nope its not that either but i found out when i enter correct user info nothing happens but when i hit refresh then it loads and says welcome user but for echo invalid still working out :)

Comment: I found the problem with your invalid login not displaying and updated my answer.

Comment: I also just added a fix for having to refresh the page to see that you are logged in.

Comment: It works and thank you, You actually stuck to your word and helped me out at the end. big respect :)

Comment: here are some bugs I found out and managed to fix it. In function hello2(HTTP) if you add HTTP it doesn't work but remove HTTP it works and to refresh a page I used echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>"); in PHP

Comment: Not a problem, I am glad I could help. I am curious did you use the echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>"); to replace the header(location:index.php) function call

Comment: yes I forgot to mention that, I replace the header with meta so whenever user logs in it will refresh the page and display the message welcome user